# Preciso imprimir uma linha l1 de uma matriz em C

Tags: c, funções, matriz, ponteiro

Após ler l1 na main, preciso passar a linha A[l1] para uma função e imprimir essa linha Imprime(A[l1]), só que dá um erro dizendo que não reconhece o parâmetro. O que pode ser?

```
void Imprime(float *A[l1]) {
    float *p;
    for(p = A[l1]; p < A[l1] + MAXCOL; p++) {
            printf("%.2f ", *p);
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde,

Acho que o seu problema está na forma como passa a matriz como parametro. Não tendo a certeza do que pretende, fiz um pequeno exemplo daquilo que acho que percebi que pretende.

Não esqueça que a numeração das linhas e colunas começa de zero, logo quando digo que quero imprimir a linha 1, na verdade estou a dizer que quero imprimir a segunda linha.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        //Definicao da tabela
        #define linhas  3
        #define colunas 3

        //Assinatura do metodos
        void ImprimirLinha(double matriz[linhas][colunas], int linhaQueQueroImprimir);

        int main()
        {
            
            double matriz[linhas][colunas] = {  1.1 , 2.2 , 3.3 ,
                                                4.4 , 5.5 , 6.6 , 
                                                7.7 , 8.8 , 9.9 
                                              };
            int linhaQueQueroImprimir = 1;
            ImprimirLinha(matriz, linhaQueQueroImprimir);

        }

        void ImprimirLinha(double matriz[linhas][colunas], int linhaQueQueroImprimir)
        {
            
            for(int i = 0; i<colunas; i++ )
            {
                printf("%0.3f |", matriz [linhaQueQueroImprimir] [i] );
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
```

Espero ter ajudado, caso afirmativo queira por favor dar up vote.